# Matching Signing between Python and Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, openssl, cryptography

I have been trying for a few days to validate some message signed with a private key in python. Note that the message has been signed using Ruby.

When I sign the same message in python I can verify it no problem. Note that I have already validated that the hash are the same.

Python code:

```
string_to_encrypt = b"aaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbCC"
sha1 = SHA.new()
sha1.update(string_to_encrypt)

# load private key
pkey = OpenSSL.crypto.load_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open('./license.pem', 'rb').read())
sign_ssl = OpenSSL.crypto.sign(pkey, sha1.digest(), 'RSA-SHA1')
b64_ssl = base64.b64encode(sign_ssl)
```

Ruby:

```
string_to_encrypt = "aaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbCC"

sha1 = Digest::SHA1.digest(string_to_encrypt)

#sign it
private_key_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'license.pem')
rsa = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(private_key_file))

signed_key = rsa.private_encrypt(sha1)

#update the license string with it
x = Base64.strict_encode64(signed_key)
```

I would expect b64_ssl and x to contain the same value and they don't. Could someone explain to me what I missing there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these code snippets is actually producing the correct signature.

In the Ruby OpenSSL library you want to be using the `sign` method, not the `private_encrypt` method, which is a low level operation that doesn’t do everything required to produce a valid signature.

In both libraries the `sign` operation performs the hashing for you, you don’t need to do this beforehand. In fact your Python code is actually hashing the data *twice*.

Try the following Python code:

```
import OpenSSL
import base64

string_to_encrypt = b"aaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbCC"

# load private key
pkey = OpenSSL.crypto.load_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, open('./license.pem', 'rb').read())
sign_ssl = OpenSSL.crypto.sign(pkey, string_to_encrypt, 'SHA1')

b64_ssl = base64.b64encode(sign_ssl)

print(b64_ssl.decode())
```

which produces the same output as this Ruby code:

```ruby
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'

string_to_encrypt = "aaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbaaaaabbbbbCC"

#sign it
private_key_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'license.pem')
rsa = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(private_key_file))

signed_key = rsa.sign('sha1', string_to_encrypt)

#update the license string with it
x = Base64.strict_encode64(signed_key)

puts x
```

Comment: Yep, thanks, though it still unclear to me how one would reproduce the output of private_encrypt in python/

Comment: @dibus2 I don’t think the Python OpenSSL library exposes the low level functions you’d need to do it (which makes sense, it’s arguably a mistake for the Ruby bindings to expose them).

Comment: Thanks for your help.